# How to add form fields to image preview?

Tags: filepond

In vue-filepond, I can drag or select files and they process fine, but I want to be able to submit user entered data along with each image.  For example, they may want to tag the image or enter a title, etc..

I can't find any documentation on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `file.setMetadata` method (https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/file/#methods) to add metadata to each file, each upload will contain a File object and a JSON object (the JSON object will contain the metadata).

Comment: Yeah but how do I show the form fields necessary to populate the metadata?

Comment: You'd have to supply those outside of FilePond, either on the same page or in a next form step. Or you have to write a custom plugin that adds the fields to each file item.